# Creating pandas.DataFrame from generator?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, generator

I'm tring to create dataframe from <generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at ...>

but throws an error :

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

The generator is returned from below function.

```
def calc_func(a):
   .........
   return array.item(), index_name

res = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
    res = executor.map(calc_func, a)
res = pd.DataFrame(res) <---- error occurred here
```

The files I want to use are so big. I tried decreasing num_workers.

**Question**

1. Why did this problem occur ?
2. How to create dataframe from generator in using ProcessPoolExecutor ?

Comment: try modifying the code to this `res = list(executor.map(calc_func, a))`

Comment: Have you put the `with ...` part under `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: Resolved!!! It seems that the problem was caused by data overflowing from memory during parallel computation.